# Encountered "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" using insrt function in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I am trying to test this sql query but I always encounter an error stating missing right parenthesis at row 1. I am guessing it has something to do with the INSTR function because my query just works fine if I replace INSTR function with a column name.

```
* row 1 
SELECT INSTR(diary.entry, 'service', 1, 1 > 0)
FROM   diary journal
WHERE  journal.req_time >= '00:00:00'
       AND journal.req_time <= '00:10:59';
```

Anyone care to help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

```
SELECT INSTR(diary.entry, 'service', 1, 1) > 0
```

- [INSTR Function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm)
- [INSTR Function *Example*](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)

Comment: I've been trying to add parenthesis here and there. And yes I was using the same link as you gave me. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.  Thanks alot!